# How to tell supervisor to restart processes when app code changed?

Tags: process, debian, tornado, supervisord

I am new to Tornado and supervisor. I have deployed a tornado app on Debian server and now it is running fine under supervisor/nginx. After that, I made a small change on the app's template file but it does not take effect apparently because the tornado processes need to be restarted. But I don't know to do so. I tried different things like

> service supervisor restart

and also in supervisorctl command line I tried restart, reload, update etc. 
But the old process are still running and the change in code still not applied. So wondering how to instruct supervisor to restart the app processes and ideally make supervisor sensitive to code change by adding some commands into supervisor.conf

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured out. Here is the answer:

```
supervisor> restart all
```

and check whether really restarted:

```
supervisor> status
tornadoes:tornado-8000           RUNNING    pid 17697, uptime 0:00:20
tornadoes:tornado-8001           RUNNING    pid 17698, uptime 0:00:20
tornadoes:tornado-8002           RUNNING    pid 17707, uptime 0:00:19
tornadoes:tornado-8003           RUNNING    pid 17712, uptime 0:00:18
```